# ssh-add not recognize running ssh-agent

Tags: scripts, ssh, ssh-agent

```
ps_out=`ps -U "$USER" | grep ssh-agent | grep -v 'grep' | grep -v $0`
result=$(echo $ps_out | grep ssh-agent)
if [ "$result" != "" ];then
    echo "ssh-agent is running"
else
    echo "ssh-agent is not running, starting now"
    eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
fi

ssh-add $FILE
```

The issue is, even though "ssh-agent is running", `ssh-add` is not able to connect 'sometimes' with a message `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent`.

How to improve the script such a way, if "ssh-agent is running" but not connecting, it should try to 're-connect' to the existing ssh-agent socket (if possible someway), else kill the existing ssh-agent and create a new one.

Why? else it may end up creating a bunch of `ssh-agent`s of no use.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is happening "sometimes"? Any error or timeout messages? You could improve the conditional using `pgrep` - something like `if pgrep -xu "$USER" ssh-agent 2>/dev/null; then ...`

Comment: `Could not open a connection to your authentication agent`